# open free chat server using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to open http://sourceforge.net/projects/freecs/?source=navbar in Netbeans IDE so I can develop,compile and run it, How can I do that ?

Comment: Download the sources and open them in Netbeans, also read the README, if there is one, on how to build the project. It should have an Ant build.xml anyway, but Netbeans can use its own script.

Comment: there are a lot of folders and I don't know how can I organize them in netbeans to start the project

Comment: I can't download the file at the moment, I'll look at it later if you still have issues.

Comment: I am now using another project .. so it is not very important if you are busy